# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: main.Players

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make the bot add the user id into the database if someone is mentioned, when someone is mentioned it compares the id value stored in the database to the mentioned id and if its not in the database it adds it  however I keep on getting the error in the title. I know what it means, its trying to insert the mentioned id to the database but it unique and already there hence it shows the given error which makes it a logic issue

```
    @commands.command()
    async def add(self, ctx, user:discord.User):
        global sql 
        global val
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
            db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT Players FROM main")
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            if user.id in result:
                await ctx.send(f"<@{user.id}> is already in teh database")
            else:
                sql = ("INSERT INTO main(Players) VALUES(?)")
                val = (user.id,)
                await ctx.send(f"<@!{user.id}> has been added")
            cursor.execute(sql,val)
            db.commit()
            cursor.close()
            db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a method that is much cleaner and works better

```
    @commands.command()
    async def add(self, ctx, user:discord.User):
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
            db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            try:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO main(Players) VALUES({user.id})")
                await ctx.send(f"<@!{user.id}> has been added")
            except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
                await ctx.send(f"<@{user.id}> is already in teh database")
            db.commit()
            cursor.close()
            db.close()
```